# peoperteis file for customised MessageDispatcher

Tags: spring-ws

I've extended Spring-WS `MessageDispatcher` to overwrite the `receive` function

```
@Component("myReceiver")
public class MyReceiver extends MessageDispatcher {
    @Override
    public void receive(MessageContext messageContext) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

But I also need a `MyReceiver.properties` file in the same package as the class. Otherwise it will fail at bean creation. Does anyone know if I can bypass this, maybe overwriting init function somewhere? I just don't want to put a properties file into that package.

The error log is something like this:

```
14:28:15.173 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MYReceiver' defined in file [C:\Apps\Projects\aref\xxxxxxxxx\MYReceiver.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [xxxxxxxx.interfaces.MYReceiver]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load 'class path resource [xxxxxxx/interfaces/MYReceiver.properties]': class path resource [xxxxxx/interfaces/MYReceiver.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:923)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588)
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems it's from parent default constructor 
`public MessageDispatcher() {
    defaultStrategiesHelper = new DefaultStrategiesHelper(getClass());
}`

Comment: Since it's a requirement of `MessageDispatcher` I think unless I rewrite its constructor there's no way to bypass it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a requirement of MessageDispatcher I think unless I rewrite its constructor there's no way to bypass it.